# Refer to variable outside of For loop

Tags: python, variables, scope

I am using this Python code to read a Windows INI file

```
from ConfigParser import SafeConfigParser

parser = SafeConfigParser()
parser.read('someinifile.ini')

for section_name in parser.sections():
    for name, value in parser.items(section_name):
        print '  %s = %s' % (name, value)
    lastkey = name
```

Works perfectly fine when I try to get the last keyname into a variable called "lastkey". But if you notice I am trying to read "name" variable outside of the "for name, value" loop. Is that illegal or incorrect? :-) I do get the last key name in lastkey but was wondering if I am doing something wrong here. I have an allergy towards badly written code so always prefer to clarify when in doubt. And I am totally new to Python too ",)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `parser.items(section_name)` is empty, name will never be initialized.
You'll get a "NameError: name 'name' is not defined" exception when evaluating the line `lastkey = name`.

So don't forget to take into account the case where `parser.items(section_name)` is empty.

Comment: I have actually initialised "lastkey" in the beginning of the function but it isn't visible in this code. And when I return lastkey it will either be empty or have the last key name. But I have not explicitly declared the "name" variable. It comes from the for loop. So I was wondering if it is right to refer to that variable outside of the for loop.

Comment: It's ok to refer to `name` outside of the for loop only if you're sure the loop will run at least one iteration. That's why you should check if `parser.items(section_name)` is empty.